# reddit does not preview my gif

Tags: javascript, html, reddit

reddit previews the gif and images. I tired to post some of my pages but reddit does not prieview my gifs when there is html/javascript added to it. then I pasted a imgur link[this is te imgur link for which reddit is previewing gif.](http://i.imgur.com/C2YjB4K.gifv) on reddit I tried to download reddits page as it is and then i placed [it here](http://nessol.cloudapp.net/u/Imgur.html) 
and posted this link to reddit preview was still not available. What can I do to get prieview?

Answer (score 1):

What is the link you're posting, and where is an example of the post with no thumbnail?

The code that determines a thumbnail is in [media.py](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/media.py); for most cases, it's specifically [`_find_thumbnail_image()`](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L706-L774), but if the link's domain is in the Embedly whitelist, then [it'll come from Embedly instead](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L777).

So for most things [an OpenGraph-enabled page](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L724-L733) will display the thumbnail you want.

The scraper has previously had problems with HTTPS urls that require SNI, but I don't know if that's still the case.

There's a distinction in reddit between **thumbnails** (what you see on `www.reddit.com`) and **image previews** (a newer system used for some mobile clients, and possibly parts of the desktop site now).  So it could be an issue with only one of those, also, but I can't say until we see the post.

There are also a maze of preferences that modify whether or not thumbnails are shown.  Your user account can disable them.  By default, it defaults to the subreddit's preferences, and the subreddit can disable them.  There's also some interaction with thumbnails of posts or subreddits that are marked NSFW, but I don't remember exactly how that operates.  And finally, certain other actions (for instance, if a moderator removes your post) will kill the thumbnail.